# Vue-Query TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vuex, react-query

I am currently starting to use Vue-Query instead of Vuex in a project. I am using Quasar,Vue and typescript.

I am trying to configure Vue-Query Library to fetch server side data

**Boot file Configurations**

```
import { boot } from "quasar/wrappers";
import { VueQueryPlugin } from "vue-query";

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  app.use(VueQueryPlugin);
});
```

**Quasar.conf.js file**

```
boot: [
  "i18n",
  "axios",
  "sentry",
  "emitter",
  "notify-defaults",
  "gtag",
  "vuequery",
]
```

**Composable file to fetch data**

```
import { useQueryClient, useQuery } from "@tanstack/vue-query";
import axios from "axios";

export default () => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["dog", "random"],
    queryFn: () => axios.call("get", "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random"),
    select: (data) => data.toString(),
response
  });
};
```

**and i am trying to access data from another component using**

```
  setup() {
    const { data } = useDogQuery();
  },
```

whenever i try to access the component that uses useDogQuery()
i got an error of

```
: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at eval (useBaseQuery.mjs:12:1)
    at ComputedRefImpl.reactiveEffect [as effect] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:42:1)
    at get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:876:1)
    at useBaseQuery (useBaseQuery.mjs:15:1)
    at useQuery (useQuery.mjs:5:1)
    at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (useDogQuery.js:5:1)
    at setup (GeneralSettings.vue:73:1)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155:1)
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7154:1)
    at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7110:1)
```

also i am having a warning in IDE

```
App •  WARNING  •  UI  in ./node_modules/vue-query/esm/index.js

export 'onScopeDispose' (imported as 'onScopeDispose') was not found in 'vue-demi' (possible exports: BaseTransition, Comment, Fragment, KeepAlive, Static, Suspense, Teleport, Text, Transition, TransitionGroup, Vue, Vue2, callWithAsyncErrorHandling, callWithErrorHandling, camelize, capitalize, cloneVNode, compatUtils, compile, computed, createApp, createBlock, createCommentVNode, createHydrationRenderer, createRenderer, createSSRApp, createSlots, createStaticVNode, createTextVNode, createVNode, customRef, defineAsyncComponent, defineComponent, defineEmit, defineEmits, defineExpose, defineProps, del, devtools, getCurrentInstance, getTransitionRawChildren, h, handleError, hydrate, initCustomFormatter, inject, install, isProxy, isReactive, isReadonly, isRef, isRuntimeOnly, isVNode, isVue2, isVue3, markRaw, mergeDefaults, mergeProps, nextTick, onActivated, onBeforeMount, onBeforeUnmount, onBeforeUpdate, onDeactivated, onErrorCaptured, onMounted, onRenderTracked, onRenderTriggered, onServerPrefetch, onUnmounted, onUpdated, openBlock, popScopeId, provide, proxyRefs, pushScopeId, queuePostFlushCb, reactive, readonly, ref, registerRuntimeCompiler, render, renderList, renderSlot, resolveComponent, resolveDirective, resolveDynamicComponent, resolveFilter, resolveTransitionHooks, set, setBlockTracking, setDevtoolsHook, setTransitionHooks, shallowReactive, shallowReadonly, shallowRef, ssrContextKey, ssrUtils, toDisplayString, toHandlerKey, toHandlers, toRaw, toRef, toRefs, transformVNodeArgs, triggerRef, unref, useAttrs, useContext, useCssModule, useCssVars, useSSRContext, useSlots, useTransitionState, vModelCheckbox, vModelDynamic, vModelRadio, vModelSelect, vModelText, vShow, version, warn, watch, watchEffect, withAsyncContext, withCtx, withDefaults, withDirectives, withKeys, withModifiers, withScopeId)
```

i think the problem is from the basic configurations with Vue-query library or i am missing something that should be intialized.

Comment: Could you provide a *runnable* [mcve] using codesandbox.io or a similar tool? What you shared so far is not enough to reproduce the problem. Also, make sure you read [installation](https://vue-query.vercel.app/#/getting-started/installation?id=installation) *carefully*. From what you shared it is obvious you skipped parts of it.